# solr query- get results without scanning files

Tags: performance, solr, indexing

I would like to execute a solr query and get only the uniquKey I've defined.
The documents are very big so defining fl='my_key' is not fast enough - all the matching documents are still scanned and the query can take hours (even though the search itself was fast - numFound takes few seconds to return).
I should mention that all the data is stored, and creating a new index is not an option.

One idea I had was to get the docIds of the results and map them to my_key in the code.
I used fl=[docid], thinking it doesn't need scanning to get this info, but it still takes too long to return.

Is there a better way to get the docIds?
Or a way to unstore certain fields without reindexing?
Or perhapse a compeletly different way to get the results without scanning all the fields?

Thanks,

Dafna

Comment: I've had very similar problems! couldn't find a way to nail it though. I hope someone have had better experience with this...

Comment: why is the search slow ? it the index size huge ? and the query searching over multiple fields ??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the only way is to break your gigantic documents in more than one. I don't see how it will be possible to only match the fields you specified and let the documents alone. This is not how Lucene works.

One could make a document that used only indexed fields that are needed to query to turn the job easier, or break the document based on the queries that are needed. Or simply adding another documents with the structure needed for these new queries. It's up to you.